# App\Profile::jenis must return a relationship instance, but "null" was returned. Was the "return" keyword used?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

> App\Profile::jenis must return a relationship instance, but "null" was
>   returned. Was the "return" keyword used? (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\user_manage\resources\views\profile\profile.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\user_manage\resources\views\profile\profile.blade.php)
>
> Model Jenis.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Profile;

class Jenis extends Model
{
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table="tbl_jenis_penyedia";
protected $primaryKey="id_jenis_penyedia";
protected $fillable=['jenis_penyedia'];

public function profile(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
}
}
```

> Model Profile.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table="tbl_profil_penyedia";
protected $primaryKey="id_profil_penyedia";
protected $fillable=['id_jenis_penyedia','nama', 'no_ktp', 'file',  'npwp', 'bank', 'no_rek', 'email', 'no_telp', 'keahlian', 'pengalaman', 'alamat', 'pendidikan'];

    public function jenis(){
        $this->hasMany(Jenis::class, 'id_jenis_penyedia', 'id_profil_penyedia');
}
}
```

> Controller

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Profile;
use App\Jenis;




class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $profile = Profile::all();
         return view('profile/homeprofile',['profile' => $profile]);
}
}
```

> view

```
@foreach($profile as $p)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
              <td>
                {{ $p->jenis->jenis_penyedia }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have forgotten to put `return` in `jenis` method.

**Profile.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table="tbl_profil_penyedia";
    protected $primaryKey="id_profil_penyedia";
    protected $fillable=['id_jenis_penyedia','nama', 'no_ktp', 'file',  'npwp', 'bank', 'no_rek', 'email', 'no_telp', 'keahlian', 'pengalaman', 'alamat', 'pendidikan'];

    public function jenis(){
        return $this->hasMany(Jenis::class, 'id_jenis_penyedia', 'id_profil_penyedia'); // PUT A `return` HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public function profile(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class,'id_jenis_penyedia', 'id_profil_penyedia');
 }
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\user_manage\resources\views\profile\profile.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\user_manage\resources\views\profile\profile.blade.php)